# Should we stop using @View annotation and only use @Component in Angular 2 components?

Tags: angular

All of the properties of the `@View` annotation are also present in `@Component`. Earlier examples used both, but since beta.8 (and maybe earlier) the code samples on angular.io website only use `@Component`. Is this the preferred way of creating components?

Comment: For now yes, until they add support for multiple views per component...

Answer (score 3):

**update**

`@View()` is about to be removed https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7495

---

It's not sure `@View` will stay supported. They discussed removing it. As far as I know they still plan to add support for multiple views but it's not decided yet how the approach will look like.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7363

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure that the `@View` decorator will be removed. You can use the `template` key in the `@Component` decorator to specify the view template. Also when you look for `@View` in the docs you can see that the example is not in line with what is written https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/View-decorator.html

To me it highly suggests that it is going to be removed.